# ng-click doesn't work inside a directive

Tags: angularjs

i'm trying to develop a directive in which i must have a clickable button, the click triggers a controller function.

Here's my code

```
'use strict';

/*global d3:false */

angular.module('myApp').directive('legends', function() {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {
    service: '=',
    buttonClick :  '&'
  },
  replace: true,

  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

    function main(data) {
      var format = d3.time.format('%d %b %y'),
        str = '<div>'+
        '<div>'+
        '<span>A</span>'+
        '<span>' + format(data[0]) + '</span>'+
        '<span>'+ data[1].toFixed(2) +'</span></div>'+
        '<div>'+
        '<span ng-click="buttonClick()"></span>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div>'+
        '<span>B</span>'+
        '<span>' + format(data[2]) + '</span>'+
        '<span>'+ data[3].toFixed(2) +'</span></div></div>';
      element.html(str);
    }

    //*********************************************************************
    scope.$watchCollection('service', function(data) {
      if (!angular.isUndefined(data) && data.length === 4) {
        main(data);

      }          
    });
  }

};
```

});

I read in another post that i have to pass the reference of the function as an attribute, this is what i did, but still nothing is triggered.

Ctrl :

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('ctrl',
    function() {
        $scope.switchObjects = function() {
          console.log('done');
        }
    }
);
```

Thank you all :)

Answer (score 0):

I may miss something but in your directive your function is called `buttonClick()` and in your controller `switchObjects`.

Comment: Yeah buttonClick is an attribute that takes the switchObjects reference in order to call the controller function using buttonClick()

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile your HTML string before injecting it to element.

Do it like this instead:

```
.directive('myCustomer', function() {

  function postlink(scope, elem, attrs) {
       scope.buttonClick = function() {
           console.log("Button clicked");
       }
  }

  return {
    link: postlink,
    template: '<html>PUT HTML HERE</html>'
  };
});
```